# Spring Boot application (using mybatis) stopped connecting to mysql after introducing CA-signed certs

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, ssl, mybatis

About a week ago, a spring boot application in a dev environment (AWS EC2 instance), which had until that point successfully connected to MySql using SSL, suddenly stopped connecting. Here's a selection from the unhelpful stack trace:

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
### The error may exist in com/domain/app/data/mybatis/mappers/SomeMapper.xml
### The error may involve com.domain.app.data.mybatis.mappers.SomeMapper.getUserByUsername
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:149)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:87)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.getUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at com.domain.app.security.SomeService.loadUserByUsername(SomeService.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Some facts:

- The exact same app build works when run from my local machine (with identical db connection info). Misconfigured application code presumably ruled out.
- mysql resides on a separate EC2 instance, and I can connect to mysql from a CLI on the 'faulty' EC2 instance. Security/ACL problems presumably ruled out.
- Connection string is of this form: jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/db_name?useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true&requireSSL=true&autoReconnect=true,{db username},{db password}. Again, this string works when used from my own machine.
- About two weeks ago, CA-signed ssl certs were added into the spring boot app within a java keystore. The same certs were not added to mysql, which is using self-generated and self-signed certs. There's a slight, if barely believable chance, that the app hasn't been tested in the faulty environment since - though I'm pretty sure I have used the environment since then.

My current thinking is that maybe the new certs in the dev application are somehow colliding with mysql's self-generated and self-signed certs, in a way that might not happen locally on my machine. But I don't know where to begin validating or testing this theory.

I've been troubleshooting this for about 7 hours, including googling the heck out of it, and reading many SO responses to related questions. Apologies if this has been answered in some way that I don't understand.

Can any of you point me either to some answers or troubleshooting pointers?